# Start Multiple Work of the same type with WorkManager

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack, android-workmanager

I want to start multiple image caching work in parallel with WorkManager. It will be using `CacheImageWorker` class. The data is retrieved from external input. The codes will look like this:

```
val cacheImageWork = mutableListOf<OneTimeWorkRequest>()
val cacheImageConstraints = WorkConstraints {
    setRequiredNetworkType(NetworkType.CONNECTED)
}
cacheImageWork.add(
    OneTimeWorkRequest<CacheImageWorker> {
        setInputData(
            workDataOf(
                CacheImageWorker.IMAGE_WORKER_DATA to data1
            )
        )
        setConstraints(cacheImageConstraints)
    }
)
cacheImageWork.add(
    OneTimeWorkRequest<CacheImageWorker> {
        setInputData(
            workDataOf(
                CacheImageWorker.IMAGE_WORKER_DATA to data2
            )
        )
        setConstraints(cacheImageConstraints)
    }
)
WorkManager.getInstance(applicationContext)
    .beginUniqueWork("", ExistingWorkPolicy.REPLACE, cacheImageWork)
    .enqueue()
```

And the doWork is basically like this

```
override suspend fun doWork(): Result {
    val inputData = inputData.getString(IMAGE_WORKER_DATA)  // retrieve data
    return cacheImage(inputData.orEmpty())
}
```

How do i differ the data 1 and data 2 since i dont think its possible to pass dynamic key for getting the data?